# Confused about RShiny within RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown

New Shiny user here. I have a simple RShiny example embedded within an RMarkdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: ""
date: "2023-05-08"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
library(shiny)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Histogram ----
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Histogram of the Old Faithful Geyser Data ----
  # with requested number of bins
  # This expression that generates a histogram is wrapped in a call
  # to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  # 1. It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
  #    re-executed when inputs (input$bins) change
  # 2. Its output type is a plot
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#007bc2", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```
````

If I knit to HTML, the HTML displays the shiny app but it's just a static image basically and you can't interact with it.

If I add this to the RMarkdown:

```
runtime:shiny
```

I get this message in the RStudio console:

```
Listening on http://101.0.0.1:1234
```

And I can navigate to the url and bring up the interactive Shiny app.  But, this doesn't really do me any good because my goal is **to be able to make a self-contained RMarkdown HTML document that contains the shiny app, and I'd like to be able to distribute that HTML document.**  In other words, I want to share around an HTML document with an embedded Shiny app without the need for hosting it on a server, etc.

Is this possible?

I also see the "publish" document option within r studio - maybe I need that?  Would that let me produce an HTML document?

Apologies for the beginner question but I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

OK. If I understand you correctly, I have to answer with your question with a NO it is not possible.

One main reason is that:

- Shiny documents must be supported by a **live R session running behind the scenes**.
- When you run a Shiny document locally, it uses **your local R session**. Usually only you can see and interact with the document.
- **If you want to share the document with people who do not have R installed**, or do not want to run the document locally, **you will have to deploy the document on a server**, and share the URL of the document. Then other people only need a web browser to visit your document.

So wrapping your Rmarkdown shiny combination in a html document won't work to the best of my knowledge:

Text and further info here https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-deploy.html

You can deploy a Shiny document:

- You can either use a hosted service provided by RStudio, or set up your own server.

For demonstrating purposes I deployed your app on shinyapps.io:
https://taja.shinyapps.io/markdown_shiny_test/

You still will have to add `runtime: shiny` to the yaml:

```
title: "Shiny_markdown"
author: "tarjae"
date: "2023-05-08"
output: html_document 
runtime: shiny
```

[image]